Why this boundary map is surjective?
Let $\mathcal Z_n(M,\mathbb Z_2)$ be the space of mod $2$ $n$-cycles supported in $M$, where $M$ is a $(n+1)$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.
Let $\mathbf I_{n+1}(M,\mathbb Z_2)$ be the space of mod $2$ integral $(n+1)$-currents
supported in $M$.
In Section 2.2 of the paper Applications of min-max methods to geometry by Marques and Neves,
it is said that the boundary map $\partial:\mathbf I_{n+1}(M,\mathbb Z_2)\to\mathcal Z_{n}(M,\mathbb Z_2)$ is surjective.
My question is: Why $\partial$ is surjective?
It seems that the Isoperimetric Inequality (fixing localization of support) only ensures that $T\in\mathcal Z_n(M,\mathbb Z_2)$ with small mass norm must be the boundary of some $S\in\mathbf I_{n+1}(M,\mathbb Z_2)$.
But it is not possible to assume an upper mass bound for all elements in $\mathcal Z_n(M,\mathbb Z_2)$.
Any hints and comments will be appreciated.
